# CiviCRM and screen reader software

Tags: accessibility

Does anyone have experience of using CiviCRM with [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS) or other screen reader software for visually impaired users?

An experienced JAWS user tried but could not get to the quick search box or the main menu items.

The topic has been raised a few times over the years, but does not seem to have a good answer yet.  For example:

- https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=18054.0
- https://civicrm.org/blog/skessler/moving-towards-accessibility
- https://london2014.civicrm.org/sessions/accessibility

(CiviCRM 4.7.14, Drupal 7)

Comment: It covers the same topics, but this question predates the other and includes links to previous discussions of the topic.  It is referenced in one of the answers to the later question.

Comment: This is an important topic and it is likely to be of interest to others in future. Looking from the perspective of someone looking for answers to this question in future, I think that the other question would be more helpful as it has some answers.  As a suggestion, @Aidan, perhaps you could edit your answer to the other question to include some of the information above?  That would keep all of the information in one place.

Comment: @WilliamMortada - good idea, edited now.